# How to retrieve archived messages in the reverse order with XMPPFramework?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm implementing retrieving XMPP chat history with XEP-0313 Message Archive Management using XMPPFramework for iOS. I receive messages page by page using XMPPFramework's class XMPPMessageArchiveManagement. I'm able to receive the pages in the reverse order providing the message before which the next page should be.

```
let resultSet = XMPPResultSet(max: 50, before: theIdOfTheOldestReceivedMessage ?? "")
self.xmppMAM?.retrieveMessageArchive(at: to,
                                     withFields: [field],
                                     with: resultSet)
```

But I also would like to receive the messages on each page in the reverse order from the last one to the first one. According to the documentation I should provide  the  element in the query:

> A client wishing for a reversed page should include the <flip-page/> element in its query, like so:

```
<iq type='set' id='q29309'>
    <query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:2'>
        <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
            <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'><value>urn:xmpp:mam:2</value></field>
            <field var='start'>\<value>2010-08-07T00:00:00Z\</value>\</field>
        </x>
        <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
            <max>10</max>
            <after>09af3-cc343-b409f\</after>
        </set>
        <flip-page/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

The source: https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html#query-paging-flip.

The problem is that I don't populate the query myself: XMPPFramework is responsible for that. The framework generates the final XML and I'm only able to provide fields and a result set. The provided fields will be **inside the x element**, the provided result set will be a separate element of the queue. But **how to provide the <flip-page/> element to the queue** with XMPPMessageArchiveManagement by XMPPFramework?

Comment: hi I try this code to retrieve the history message but unable to retrieve the message. please share the function or procedure to retrieve  history messages.

Comment: Hi @AbishekThangaraj. Please check how do you parse received MAM messages. A usual message is just <message></message>, but a MAM message has the following structure: <message><result><forwarded><delay></delay><message></message></forwarded></result></message>. You need the <message></message> packed inside <forwarded></forwarded>. This packed message you can parse as a usual message.

Comment: hi @Dmytryk Skorokhod I think I ask question wrongly. Actually I never received this delegate 

 func xmppMessageArchiveManagement(_ xmppMessageArchiveManagement: XMPPMessageArchiveManagement, didReceiveMAMMessage message: XMPPMessage) {
      if let body = message.mamResult?.forwardedMessage{
        print("didReceiveMAMMessage", body)
      }
        print("didReceiveMAMMessage", message)
    }

Please visit my question and request you to clarify my doubt 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749713/retrieve-the-xmpp-archived-message-from-ejabberd-serverchat-history)

Comment: @DmytrykSkorokhod were you able to add **<flip-page/> element** with XMPPMessageArchiveManagement by XMPPFramework?